# Campo pesquisa no Ionic, preciso fechar quando o usuário clicar em "Ir" ou "OK" do Teclado

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um campo de pesquisa no topo, que é apenas um filtro, assim:

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-light">
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" ng-submit="fechaTeclado()" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Com o filtro pegando o `ng-model="q"` e filtrando em:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:q | orderBy:someModel | unique: 'cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta'" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null">
```

Que funciona muito bem, mas o cliente deseja que, ao clicar no botão "Ir" ou "OK" do teclado, o mesmo feche. Como posso fazer isso?

Esse filtro já vai filtrando automático. E não é um formulário, é apenas um input text.

Comment: Este ng-submit="fechaTeclado()"  foi uma tentativa falha de fechar o teclado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única forma que funcionou foi transformando em form:

```
<form ng-submit="fechaTeclado()">
        <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-light">
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="text" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" type="submit" ng-submit="fechaTeclado()" ng-click="fechaTeclado()"/>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="OK" ng-click="fechaTeclado()"/>

            </label>
        </div>
        </form>
```

E com o plugin do cordova $cordovaKeyboard + a função:

```
$scope.fechaTeclado = function () {
        $cordovaKeyboard.close()
    };
```

Só assim, pra resolver, sem alterar o layout.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o seu botão com o `type="submit"`, para que ele seja identificado pelo `device` e adicione o `go`.

```
<input type="submit" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" ng-submit="fechaTeclado()" />
```

Comment: Fica o botão "Submit" na barra de procura inteira e não aber o teclado...